# Get comments by instagram api

Tags: java, instagram, instagram-api

When I'm trying to get comments to media, it returns me only access token owner users comment, and no other users comments.

Query:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/"+mediaId+"/comments?access_token="+token
```

So final query looks like:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/1162251688307718037_1824437940/comments?access_token=token
```

Answer:

```
`{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"created_time":"1453069290","text":"comment_text_here","from":{"username":"username","profile_picture":"profile_picture","id":"user_id","full_name":"full_name"},"id":"1164752089812694405"}]}'
```

Get media id:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token="+token+"&count=30
```

Getting media id list

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(comments);
    JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
    if (data.length()>0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) data.get(i);
            list.add(obj.getString("id"));
            //System.out.println(obj.getString("id"));
        }
    }
```

Where my mistake or is it api instagram limits for sandbox app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in sandbox mode, it will return media only from sandbox authorized users, if u add a user that has commented to your sandbox, then that comment will show up in API response.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

> To help you develop and test your app, the users and media available
>   in Sandbox mode are real Instagram data (i.e. what is normally visible
>   in the Instagram app), but with the following conditions:
>
> - Apps in sandbox are restricted to 10 users
> - Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from each of those users
> - Reduced API rate limits

Comment: will it show me comments for other users as well if it is not in sandbox mode